# Compare Java List Vectors

Tags: java, list

I have two lists (Matches and Motifpoisitions). I want to combine the list in the following way: For all i such that i%2 = 1, look for Motifpoistions(k) = Matches(i) +1. And then set Matches(i)=Motifpostions(k+1). Additionally, I want to remove i and i-1 if k could not be found.

For example, If matches are (1,3,10,12) and Motifpositions is (4,8) then the final vector should be (1,8). Since 4 = 3+1, I replaced 3 with 8. And since there is no value in Motifpositions equal to 12+1, remove 10 and 12. 
Here is what I am trying so far

```
for( int i = 1; i < matches.size(); i = i+2){
    int motifmatched = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k <motifpositions.size(); k++){
        if(motifpositions.get(k) == matches.get(i)+1){
            matches(i) = motifpositions(k+1); 
            motifmatched ++; 
        }
    }
    if(motifmatched ==0){
        matches.remove(i);
        matches.remove(i-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. You've told us what you're trying to do, and provided your code so far, which is great! Please *also* tell us what's not working: what is your code doing incorrectly, or where is it erroring and what error is it throwing?

Comment: a) `motifpositions(k+1); ` - don(t you need a `get`? b) same code will also cause out of bounds exception

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you've used nested loops.

Try this code, which prints `[1, 8]` as requested:-

```
List<Integer> matches = new LinkedList<>();
matches.add(1);
matches.add(3);
matches.add(10);
matches.add(12);

List<Integer> motifPositions = new LinkedList<>();
motifPositions.add(4);
motifPositions.add(8);

for (int i = 1; i < matches.size(); i += 2) {
    int indexOfSumInMotifpositions = motifPositions.indexOf(matches.get(i) + 1);
    if (indexOfSumInMotifpositions > -1) {
        matches.set(i, motifPositions.get(indexOfSumInMotifpositions + 1));
    } else {
        matches.remove(i);
        matches.remove(i - 1);
    }
}
System.out.println(matches);
```